# What is the meaning of this sentences?

Tags: meaning, sentence, conjunctions

> Perceptions of threat are hypothesized to be influenced by one’s own vulnerability, and thus to be greater among those individuals who are
> experiencing more difficult economic conditions or vulnerability.

At this sentence I couldn't understand what the meaning of the section ",and thus to be...". Is *thus to be* a phrase or something else?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. What do you think sentence one and two mean?

Comment: In sentence one, "and thus to be" refers back to "perceptions of threat." So the second part of the sentence is "<perceptions of threat> are greater among those individuals..."

Comment: Does it mean, like …When our own vulnerability is the reason for threat (indirectly saying that we should not be vulnerable), we feel better among others who are more vulnerable…?

Comment: Although some studies find that hosting refugees may be economically beneficial because of their participation in the local economy, the largest benefits are in the long-term. Yes, the largest benefits are in the long term, whereas hosting costs are sustained immediately and are thus more politically salient.

Comment: Welcome! There is a rule that we can ask only one question at a time. Please can you edit your question to remove the second sentence. Then you can post a new question about that. Thank you

Comment: It's a whole lot of words to say that people who are being threatened feel more scared, and that poor people with few resources feel even more even more scared. None of which is news, but which sounds like news if it's said in a sufficiently high-falutin way.

Answer (score 1):

> Perceptions of threat are hypothesized to be influenced by one’s own
> vulnerability, and thus to be greater among those individuals who are
> experiencing more difficult economic conditions or vulnerability.

This is not a particular phrase. In this context, "thus" means the same as "therefore".

Here is a paraphrase.

*Perceptions of threat are hypothesized to be influenced by one’s own vulnerability, and therefore perceptions of threat are greater among those individuals who are experiencing more difficult economic conditions or vulnerability.*